# Protractor classname locator fails but xpath locator passes

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Protractor assertion passes with the xpath locator but not with the classname locator.

**Works**

`var menu = element(by.xpath('/html/body/page/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/span'));`

Passes it's assertion.

**Fails**

`var menu = element(by.classname('menu'));`

Yields the following errors:

In chrome,

> Failed: element not interactable

In firefox,

> Failed: Element  could not be scrolled into view

Why might this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem, I had multiple elements with the same classname. What protractor was doing was taking the first element with that class. What it should have been doing was taking the second but related element with that class.

I tried  `element.all(by.className('menu')).get(1)` and it works perfectly.

Thanks for your help @yong and @Kacper for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

`by.classname()` will be convert to `by.css()` by protractor inside.

`by.classname('menu')` will be convert to `by.css('.menu')`.

Try css selector: `.menu` manually in chrome DevTools and check the first element found by `.menu` is same as by the xpath:  `/html/body/page/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/span`.

Comment: It would seem that they are the same. For the css selector I get `by.css(body > page > div.main > div.body > div.body-main > div > span)` But I get the following error >Failed: No element found using locator

Answer (score 1):

We're not able to suggest any reliable css selector without seeing DOM, especially when you don't use `menu` class in your xpath selector.
If you want to convert it into css selector, you can try:

`element(by.css('page > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(1) >span'));` or any shorter equivalent.